# Randomly Picking a number within a Range of 1-1680

Tags: python, winapi, python-2.7, syntax

What I'm trying to do with this script is create cords for the mouse to travel too but I want the X cords to move to a location which is in the range of 0-1670.

```
import win32api
import win32con


def move(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))


move(1670,955)
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: [random](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

move(random.randint(0, 1670), 955)
```

Answer (score 0):

according to https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

It's `random.randrange(start, stop[, step])`, so

```
random.randrange(0, 1670)
```

Google and docs are your friend, learn to use them.